# How to free memory that is given for the pointer variable itself?

Tags: c++, pointers

When we create a pointer variable, memory is allocated for the pointer itself(4/8 bytes). How to free that memory< when the pointer becomes redundant

> after

```
delete pointer;
pointer = NULL;
```

Comment: You don't.  Like all other "regular" variables, you just let it go out of scope.

Comment: You don't need to assign null to the pointer after freeing it

Comment: You only `delete` things you create with `new`.

Comment: How did you allocate the memory for the pointer? If you used `new`, then you `delete`. If it is an automatic variable, the memory will be automatically freed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You mean that it is freed by the GC as it is no longer used, don't you?

Comment: No, there is no GC in C++. Show us how you allocated the memory for the pointer.

Comment: The pointer is allocated on the stack. When the function in which it is declared returns, the  stack  pointer is decremented (or incremented, depending on the implementation), effectively releasing that memory along with any other local variables.

Comment: The most important thing to learn about pointers is that there is nothing special about pointers. Just like with other variables, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Hati_ko I'd thoroughly recommend you shouldn't use raw pointers and manual memory management at all. In 99% of the real world use cases YAGNI.

Comment: @Oblivion -- whether or not you need to assign null to the pointer after freeing it can depend on a design decision. Setting a pointer to null is often used to indicate that the pointer currently doesn't point at anything. You're right that automatically assigning null often results in unnecessary assignments. My pet peeve is in a destructor; `delete ptr; ptr = NULL; }` where it's totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When variables lifetime ends. This depends on the type of variable but if we look at the simplest an automatic variable in function scope this is when it goes out of scope any space they did utilize will be recovered by the system (and if they have destructors this will also be called).

```
// Looking at the simplest type of variable.
// An automatic variable in function scope.
{
    int*   pointer = /* allocate memory somehow */;
    ...
    // STUFF
    delete pointer;
}
// pointer is now out of scope.
// If it did occupy any memory then any memory has now been reclaimed.
```

Note: The pointer may never be allocated any memory. The pointer may just live in a register in the CPU.

Now there are lots of other types of variable. But the same rule applies when there lifetime is over any memory foot print is reclaimed. With local variables this is when they go out of scope. With member variables this is when their parent is destroyed etc..

Comment: "allocate memory somehow" - it had better be allocated via `new` if you are going to `delete ` it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Sure eventually. But you could call a function that calls new.

Comment: Even in a scope block, you better use smart pointers to completely remove the possibility of forgetting to `delete` a dynamically allocated memory block

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    int * p; //created on stack
    // code goes here
}
```

in this case you dont need to delete the pointer itself as it was created on stack so it will be destroyed automatically when its scope ends